# C++ UDP bind() always returns -1

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, bind

I want to send an `UDP` packet.

I'm using `Visual Studio C++ 2017`, and I've linked the lib `Ws2_32.Lib`

This is the sample code needed to illustrate this issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <ws2tcpip.h>


int main()
{
    sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    memset(&serverAddress, 0, sizeof(serverAddress));
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;// AF_UNSPEC;
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(20000);

    int result = 0;
    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); //socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    result = bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
    if (result == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "error!!!!!! Why?";
    }
}
```

Why can't I simply `bind()` the `socket` here?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453517/udp-unable-to-bind-socket) post here, but this didn't helped me, since this one was just a parenthesis problem.

Comment: And the error was?

Comment: @EJP please read the title.

Comment: I have read not only your title but your entire post, and your inane comment. You have not provided the error. -1 is not an error. It is a *return value* which *indicates* an error. The actual error for a Winsock call is provided by `WSAGetLastError()`. This is rather basic. Please fix your code to print the error value and include the result in your post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the answer. I wasn't creating the socket correctly.

```
//init
int server_length;
int port = 20000;
const int STRLEN = 256;
char recMessage[STRLEN];
char sendMessage[STRLEN];
char *sendMes = "SERVER READY";
WSADATA wsaData;
SOCKET mySocket;
SOCKET myBackup;
SOCKET acceptSocket;
sockaddr_in myAddress;

//create socket
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != NO_ERROR)
{
    cerr << "Socket Initialization: Error with WSAStartup\n";
    system("pause");
    WSACleanup();
    exit(10);
}

mySocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (mySocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    cerr << "Socket Initialization: Error creating socket" << endl;
    system("pause");
    WSACleanup();
    exit(11);
}

myBackup = mySocket;

//bind
myAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
myAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
myAddress.sin_port = htons(port);

if (bind(mySocket, (SOCKADDR*)&myAddress, sizeof(myAddress)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    cerr << "ServerSocket: Failed to connect\n";
}
```

Comment: You weren't initializing Winsock. You were creating the socket correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You have to call **WSAStartup()** at the beginning for WinSock:

```
WSADATA data;
::WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &data);
```

And you have to call **WSACleanup()** at the end:

```
::WSACleanup();
```

But before continuing, consider about IPV6.  *sockaddr_in* only works with IPV4.